# Convert a bytes dictionary to JSON

Tags: python, json

I have what looks like a bytes dictionary being returned from an API and I'm trying to convert it to JSON with no success at the moment.

Sample data:

```
>>> endpoint_req.content
b'{\n  "ERSEndPoint" : {\n    "id" : "7c0504654",\n    "name" : "E123",\n    "description" : "",\n    "mac" : "E123",\n    "profileId" : "",\n    "staticProfileAssignment" : false,\n    "groupId" : "7fe99b20-322b-11ea-b4b9-3a35502b4b8b",\n    "staticGroupAssignment" : true,\n    "portalUser" : "",\n    "identityStore" : "",\n    "identityStoreId" : "",\n    "link" : {\n      "rel" : "self",\n      "href" : "https://",\n      "type" : "application/json"\n    }\n  }\n}'
>>> edata = json.dumps(endpoint_req.content.decode('utf-8'))
>>> edata
'"{\\n  \\"ERSEndPoint\\" : {\\n    \\"id\\" : \\"7c0504654...
>>> edata['ERSEndPoint']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError
edata = ast.literal_eval(edata)
>>> edata['ERSEndPoint']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
>>> edata
'{\n  "ERSEndPoint" : {\n    "id" : "7c0504654",\n...
```

Each way I've tried to convert is just failing, I know it's likely something simple but I'm unsure of what it is.

Comment: `json.loads`? `json.dumps` is to turn Python objects *to* JSON. You don't have "a bytes dictionary", that's JSON, and you're not trying to convert it *to* JSON you're trying to convert if *from* JSON.

Comment: god dammit, im tired! obviously its loads (facepalm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to load with `loads` and first decode with `decode`.

```
import json
edata = json.loads(endpoint_req.content.decode("utf-8"))
edata
{'ERSEndPoint': {'id': '7c0504654', 'name': 'E123', 'description': '', 'mac': 'E123', 'profileId': '', 'staticProfileAssignment': False, 'groupId': '7fe99b20-322b-11ea-b4b9-3a35502b4b8b', 'staticGroupAssignment': True, 'portalUser': '', 'identityStore': '', 'identityStoreId': '', 'link': {'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https://', 'type': 'application/json'}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might feed `bytes` directly into `json.loads` as long as you remember to provide correct encoding that is:

```
import json
content = b'{\n  "ERSEndPoint" : {\n    "id" : "7c0504654",\n    "name" : "E123",\n    "description" : "",\n    "mac" : "E123",\n    "profileId" : "",\n    "staticProfileAssignment" : false,\n    "groupId" : "7fe99b20-322b-11ea-b4b9-3a35502b4b8b",\n    "staticGroupAssignment" : true,\n    "portalUser" : "",\n    "identityStore" : "",\n    "identityStoreId" : "",\n    "link" : {\n      "rel" : "self",\n      "href" : "https://",\n      "type" : "application/json"\n    }\n  }\n}'
edata = json.loads(content, encoding='utf-8')
print(edata)
```

Output:

```
{'ERSEndPoint': {'id': '7c0504654', 'name': 'E123', 'description': '', 'mac': 'E123', 'profileId': '', 'staticProfileAssignment': False, 'groupId': '7fe99b20-322b-11ea-b4b9-3a35502b4b8b', 'staticGroupAssignment': True, 'portalUser': '', 'identityStore': '', 'identityStoreId': '', 'link': {'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https://', 'type': 'application/json'}}}
```